# How to center \rhead

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I currently have my header as follows

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{39pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{Logo}}
% Frist page only header
\fancypagestyle{first}{% 
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{Logo}}
\rhead{\tiny Some College\\Some place\\Some department\\Some date\\}
}
```

But the problem is that I want the right side of the header to be centred like:

[image: What I want]

But I get

[image: What I get]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does `\begin{center}...\end{center}` within `\rhead{...}` not work?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the `center` environment adds additional vertical spacing so i don't think it's a good solution

Comment: @cgnieder: True, I should have written `\centering`, but I have not tried out... and there are already two solutions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your right header in a `c`entred `tabular` (vertically aligned with the `[b]`aseline):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{34pt}% To make fancyhdr and LaTeX happy in terms of the header height
% First page only header
\fancypagestyle{first}{% 
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
  \lhead{\includegraphics[height=2.5\baselineskip]{example-image}}
  \rhead{\tiny \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}Some College\\Some place\\Some department\\Some date\end{tabular}}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\thispagestyle{first}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Note that chapter first pages are usually set in the `plain` page style. If you wish to avoid manually setting things this way (using `\thispagestyle{first}`, say), you can adjust the `plain` page style directly.

Comment: the image and text aren't vertically aligned.  the text is too low.

Comment: The alignment of the `tabular` structure can be fixed by providing the `[b]` positioning spec.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, @Mico: Sorry, yes. Fixed.`

Comment: `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 29.4733pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.` (The number you get can be different)

Comment: @egreg: I had the "correct" head height in the example code, but removed the regular `fancy` page style set by the OP, and incidentally also the head height setting...

Comment: What I wanted to say, is that the height of this first header should be irrelevant; or some other change to the page geometry should be made, in order not to have too low headers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something slightly more complicated.

1. You have to first measure the height of the logo, assuming it's taller than the material in the right header field
2. The material must be centered with a `tabular`
3. The tabular must be inserted in a `minipage` so we're able to center it vertically with respect to the logo
4. Everything must be smashed so that `fancyhdr` won't change the head height, due to excessive height in the first header

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,fancyhdr}
% First page only header
\newsavebox{\logobox}
\sbox{\logobox}{\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth]{example-image}}
\fancypagestyle{first}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyhead[L]{%
    \leavevmode\smash{\usebox{\logobox}}%
  }
  \fancyhead[R]{%
    \leavevmode\smash{%
      \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\logobox][c]{\textwidth}
      \tiny\raggedleft
      \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      Some College\\Some place\\Some department\\Some date
      \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\thispagestyle{first}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If the logo is lower than the material on the right, a similar trick can be devised.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
  \rhead{\tiny\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
       Some College\\
       Some place\\
       Some department\\
       Some date\end{tabular}}
```

[image]